# Scala how to get annotated classes

Tags: scala, annotations, scala-reflect, reflections

In Java i can use `org.reflections` for scanning packages and searching annotated classes.

Like this:

```
Reflections ref = new Reflections("my.path");
Set<Class<?>> set = ref.getTypesAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class);
```

How to get annotated classes in scala? I use `scala 2.11` and `scala-reflect`.

P.S. `org.reflections` works nice in scala, but i search native instrument.

Comment: If you can get it in two lines of Java, why bother. I've had the same question at some point and finally just stuck with using a Java library in Scala.

Comment: @LodewijkBogaards I try to use only scala but it is not always possible(and just for fun:)

Comment: You can still use Scala, but with a little help of a Java library :)